# Get the Count of Element in JS which has the specified Value (Without JQUERY)

Tags: javascript

I have an requirement in JS where, i want to get the count of li element which has the same inner value. What is the best way to do it ? I know we can achieve this in Jquery easily using find and contains but i don't want to use jquery.

I want the length of li elements has the Same Value.

For Eg: Say i want to find out how many LI has the value 'A'.

Below is the JS i have tried, which i think is not the best cos if i have say around 10,000 LI then i will have to loop through all the elements get their values and check if its what i want or no, which will surely hit the performance.

Note : LI element is added runtime with their Value.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="s_1" id="ULE">
    <li class="r1">A</li>
    <li class="r1">A</li>    
    <li class="r1">B</li>
    <li class="r1">A</li>  
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var LI = document.getElementsByClassName('r1');
var cnt = 0;
for(var i=0;i<LI.length;i+=1){
    if(LI[i].innerHTML == 'A'){
        cnt += 1;
    }
}

if(cnt === 4) 
      alert('working good!!');
```

> [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvg5veeL/)

Comment: What's wrong with your code? If you add another `A` element, there are 4 of them and the alert happens.

Comment: Possible that you neee use === instead of ==

Comment: @Marciano Why would you need to do that when you know it only contains a number?

Comment: @Barmar ???`innerHTML` contains number???

Comment: `if(cnt === 4)`  is just adding confusion to your question

Comment: Sorry, thought you were talking about `cnt`. But there's no need to use `===` when comparing with `'A'`.

Comment: Your code works fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uvg5veeL/2/

Comment: Side note: I'd use `document.querySelectorAll(".r1")` rather than `document.getElementsByClassName("r1")`. It has better cross-browser support (such as IE8).

Comment: *"I know we can achieve this in Jquery easily using find and contains but i don't want to use jquery."* jQuery's not going to do it any faster for you. jQuery is just a layer on top of the DOM (with lots of useful stuff in it). If you're using the DOM directly, unless you're doing it in a roundabout fashion (you're not), jQuery's not going to do it any faster for you.

Comment: if(cnt === 4) is just for example. 4 is not hard coded it depends on some value that comes from server. Main question here is for performance

Comment: @Barmar == only checks what type the object is, not the precise string. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript

Comment: @Marciano You're crazy. Of course it compares the strings. The difference between `===` and `==` is what happens when the two arguments are different types. `==` will coerce one of them to the other type and then compare the values, `===` will not coerce and always considers them unequal.

Comment: @Marciano `==` will sometimes say things are equal when `===` says they're not. It's never the case that `==` says they're unequal but `===` says they are.

Comment: @Barmar My sentence is confusing, my bad. But the point what I am trying to make is that === checks the exact value of an object, not only the object type.

Comment: @Marciano I know. But in this case, how would that help? `innerHTML` is either a string or `null`. When it's a string, `innerHTML == 'A'` will compare them just like `===` does. If it's null, `null == 'A'` will never be true, and changing it to `===` won't change that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a better way to improve the performance. If you have nothing but the DOM to work with (e.g. if the data is from user input), and not the underlying data structure from which you created the data, AFAICT there is no other structure to collect all of the elements than into an array-type structure, which will then require O(n) time to check every element.

Rather than have a count target, which is therefore dependent on the amount of list elements, try instead a function to handle the data, which increases the convenience somewhat:

```
function isEveryElementEqual(nodeList) {
    val = nodeList[0].innerHTML;
    for (var i=1; i<nodeList.length; i++) {
        if (nodeList[i].innerHTML !== val) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var LI = document.getElementsByClassName('r1');

console.log(isEveryElementEqual(LI)); // Returns false with the above HTML
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to search all `<li>` in the document. `getElementsByClassName` can be applied to an element, it will then only search within that element. So you can do:

```
var LI = document.getElementById('ULE').getElementsByClassName('r1');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uvg5veeL/3/)

You can also simplify this with `querySelectorAll`:

```
var LI = docuement.querySelectorAll('#ULE .r1');
```

Comment: Excellent point about working only within the desired element. Re your second example, remember that selectors are processed right-to-left, so your simplified solution first finds elements with the class `.r1`, then eliminates ones that aren't descendants of `#ULE`. `document.getElementById("ULE").querySelectorAll(".r1");` is dramatically faster in a large DOM.

Comment: I've read `querySelectorAll` is slower than getting by `id` / `className`.

Comment: @Eclecticist: `getElementById` is **dramatically** faster than any other method of finding elements. On most browsers that have it, `getElementsByClassName` is indeed faster than `querySelectorAll`, presumably because it doesn't have to do full selector parsing and generalized matching. It's not likely to *matter*, but... :-)

Comment: Probably, since it has to parse the selector and then figure out what to do, and what to do is what getting by id and classname does.

Comment: @Barmar: I realized I'd made *the classic* stupid mistake above: I made an assumption about browser code performance which I hadn't tested. But I got lucky this time and was correct *(whew)*: http://jsperf.com/selector-with-id-root-vs-get-by-id-and-select :-)

Comment: But even faster is my first version: http://jsperf.com/selector-with-id-root-vs-get-by-id-and-select/2